# Pass command parameter from the xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, mvvm, icommand

I try to do something like this:

```
<DataGrid Name="myGrid" ItemSource="{Binding Path=MyCollection}">
   <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
       <ContextMenu>
          <MenuItem 
              Command="{Binding RemoveRow}" 
              CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=myGrid, Path=SelectedItem}">
       </ContextMenu>
   </DataGridContextMenu>
</DataGrid>
```

but I got null always (I tried also SelectedIndex and SelectedValue)

if I pass the following parameter to the execution code, it works:

```
<MenuItem Command="{Binding RemoveRow}" CommandParameter="1">
```

Comment: Did you verify that SelectedItem is not null?

Comment: I don't know if that works for you but you can just check the datagrid SelectedItem property.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try something like this in your CommandParameter,

```
<DataGrid.ContextMenu>
     <ContextMenu>
           <MenuItem Header="MyHeader" 
                     Command="{Binding MyCommand}"
                     CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem}" />
</DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

I already tested it and it should work.

Answer (score 18):

It doesn't work because the `ContextMenu` is not part of the visual or logical tree of the `DataGrid`, so it doesn't inherit the `DataContext`.

As far as I know, there is know easy solution to this problem using only the built-in binding system. However, using a simple "proxy" class as explained [here](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/), you can work around this problem:

```
<DataGrid Name="myGrid" ItemSource="{Binding Path=MyCollection}">
   <DataGrid.Resources>
       <local:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}" />
   </DataGrid.Resources>
   <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
       <ContextMenu>
          <MenuItem 
              Command="{Binding Data.RemoveRow, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" 
              CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=myGrid, Path=SelectedItem}">
       </ContextMenu>
   </DataGridContextMenu>
</DataGrid>
```

However you still have a problem: `ElementName=myGrid` doesn't work (again, because `ContextMenu` isn't in the visual or logical tree of the `DataGrid`, so it's not in the same name scope). A simple solution is to bind the `SelectedItem` of the `DataGrid` to a property of the ViewModel, and use that property instead of the command parameter:

```
<DataGrid Name="myGrid" ItemSource="{Binding Path=MyCollection}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
   <DataGrid.Resources>
       <local:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}" />
   </DataGrid.Resources>
   <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
       <ContextMenu>
          <MenuItem 
              Command="{Binding Data.RemoveRow, Source={StaticResource proxy}}">
       </ContextMenu>
   </DataGridContextMenu>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Nice answer! i did not know this issue. but explainme plaese if its like this why when i clicked the menu item the RemoveRow is actually called even if the ContextMenu is no part of the tree?

Comment: what do you mean "yes, that's right"? i didnt understand why Command="{Binding RemoveRow}" working if the ContextMenu dont know about th DataContext? can you explain me this please?

Comment: OK, I misunderstood your question, I thought you were asking for confirmation... You can find more details in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ContextMenuDataContext.aspx)