# Command Parameter Datagrid SelectedItems is null

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, datagrid, commandparameter

So I found this answer [Pass command parameter from the xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154202/pass-command-parameter-from-the-xaml) which I think got me most of the way there. The problem I am having is when I select a row in the datagrid it triggers the command but the selected items is null.

What I don't know, and suspect is the issue, is what type should I be passing the selecteditems to in the view model? Currently I am using IList as shown in my viewmodel code:

```
namespace Project_Manager.ViewModel
{
public class ProjectSummaryViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public ProjectSummaryViewModel()
    {
        ProjectSummary = DatabaseFunctions.getProjectSummaryData();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ProjectSummaryModel> projectsummary;
    public ObservableCollection<ProjectSummaryModel> ProjectSummary
    {
        get { return projectsummary; }
        set
        {
            projectsummary = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ProjectSummary");
        }
    }

    public ICommand DeleteRowCommand
    {
        get { return new ParamDelegateCommand<IList<ProjectSummaryModel>>(DeleteRow); }
    }

    private void DeleteRow(IList<ProjectSummaryModel> projectsummaryselected)
    {
        string name = projectsummaryselected[0].ProjectName;
    }
}
}
```

The XAML view code for the datagrid looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="Project_Manager.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<!--<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
</Window.Resources>-->

    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/> <!--Menu row-->
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/> <!--button row-->
        <RowDefinition/> <!--Current projects-->
        <RowDefinition/> <!--Completed projects-->
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--<Menu>
        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem Header="New Project Management" CommandTarget="{Binding NewTable}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Open Project Management"/>
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem Header="Exit"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="View">
            <MenuItem x:Name="ViewCompleted" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="True" Header="View Completed Projects List"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Project Management">
            <MenuItem Header="New Project"/>
        </MenuItem>

    </Menu>-->

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="Create New Project" Command="{Binding Path=NewProjectCommand}"/>
        <!--<Button Content="View Details" Visibility="{Binding Source={x:Reference Name=CurrentProjectsDataGrid}, Path=IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>-->
    </StackPanel>

    <Grid Grid.Row="2">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="Current Projects" Background="LemonChiffon"/>
        <DataGrid x:Name="SummaryDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectSummary}" Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}">
            <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Delete Row" Command="{Binding DeleteRowCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>


    <!--<DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Project Name" Binding=""/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Team Name"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Latest Update"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date Started"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>-->

    <!--<Grid Grid.Row="3">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        --><!--<TextBlock Text="Completed Projects" Background="LightGreen" Visibility="{Binding Source={x:Reference Name=ViewCompleted}, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}" Visibility="{Binding Source={x:Reference Name=ViewCompleted}, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Project Name"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Team"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date Completed"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>--><!--
    </Grid>-->
</Grid>
```

And just in case this is a command implementation problem here is the custom Delegate Command that I am using:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Project_Manager.Common
{
public class ParamDelegateCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    private Action<T> executeMethod;

    //private Func<T, bool> canExecuteMethod;

    public ParamDelegateCommand(Action<T> executeMethod) //, Func<T, bool> canExecuteMethod)
    {
        this.executeMethod = executeMethod;
        //this.canExecuteMethod = canExecuteMethod;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true; //canExecuteMethod((T)parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        executeMethod((T)parameter);
    }
}
}
```

I have searched around and can find plenty of examples for the XAML binding I just can't seem to find the other half of it. So what type should be in the viewmodel? Alternatively what is the actual problem?

Edit: Just noticed an error the debug window that might help someone

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=SelectedItems; DataItem=null; target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'CommandParameter' (type 'Object')

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using context menu please refer the below code to get SelectedItems.

```
<ContextMenu>
    <MenuItem Header="Delete Row" Command="{Binding DeleteRowCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItems}"/>
</ContextMenu>
```

Also Selecteditems is an IList so change the code like below.

```
public ICommand DeleteRowCommand
{
    get { return new ParamDelegateCommand<IList>(DeleteRow); }
}

private void DeleteRow(IList projectsummaryselected)
{
    string name = (projectsummaryselected[0] as ProjectSummaryModel).ProjectName;
}
```

Comment: that mostly worked! I am now getting the selecteditem but if I use 'string name = projectsummaryselected[0].ProjectName;' I get an error **object does not contain a definition for ProjectName and no extension method could be found**. Which is strange because if I look at 'projectsummaryselected[0].ToString();' then I see ProjectName with a value. How do I get to it?

Comment: edit my answer. you need to typecast to get the list.

Comment: In case anyone else finds this and gets to the same point; with the help of the answer here: [How to get single value of List<object>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19206676/how-to-get-single-value-of-listobject) I was able to figure it out. I ended up using a 'foreach (ProjectSummaryModel item in projectsummaryselected) { item.ProjectName} got me the value. Thank you for everyones help!!!

Comment: sorry just saw your comment. That worked too! And is a lot nicer than a foreach loop. Thank you again!!!

Comment: I tried this and the IList if always empty. How are the selected items be cleared everything I right click?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<MenuItem Header="Delete Row" Command="{Binding DeleteRowCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you @Muds for the response but I am still getting null. I edited my post with an error message that I just noticed in the debug window. Not sure if that would help or not.

Comment: I have slightly changed the code , and this works for me

Comment: if it still wont work, post some more code to understand

Comment: I am still getting null. I have posted more code. It is a small project so there isn't too much more. I included the DelegateCommand class in case that is causing the problem